# Python: modulus using anding

Tags: python, modulus

I'm writing a program using bitarray
for example:

```
bytePerInt = sys.getsizeof(1)
class BitMap(object):

    def __init__(self,bits):
        self.bitsPerInt = 8*bytePerInt
        size = bits/self.bitsPerInt+1
        self.bitarray = [0]*size

    #set the bit of pos as 1
    def setBit(self,pos):
        index = pos/self.bitsPerInt
        shift = pos%self.bitsPerInt
        operator = self.bitarray[index]
        mask = 1<<shift
        operator|=mask
        self.bitarray[index] = operator
```

I want to get the modulus with adding instead of %, such as num&31 instead of num%32.
However, bytePerInt is 24 in my computer, bitsPerInt is 24*8=192, which is not a power-of-2-number, as a result, I can't anding 191 to get the modulus, so what I can do?

Comment: 24 bytes per int? Are you sure?

Comment: BTW, there is `int.bit_length` method you might be interested in

Comment: @danielkullmann yes, when I print sys.getsizeof(1), the result is 24

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` doesn't do what you think, IMO. `sys.getsizeof('1')` -> `38`

Comment: >...and the essential element in the array is Int < what is this array?

Comment: @warwaruk 0 and 1 in the array, sorry

Comment: @warwaruk why sys.getsizeof() doesn't do what I want?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` returns how much memory Python spends on the object, including metadata.

Comment: You better tell us why you need this bit array. I think there is a much better way for your goal.

Comment: @warwaruk I just want to use python to implement bit array for fun. and I found a blog about generating prime. The blog introduce a strategy to generate prime by bitarry. like this: ba->bitarray = malloc(ba->intsInArray * ba->bytesPerInt); So I think python could also do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others I'm not sure what you mean by `and the essential element in the array is Int`, but if you are creating a bit array of booleans (1 and 0), use [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray).

Comment: Is there any way to implement bitarray? not to use the library?

Comment: @remy why would you want that?